# apex:param value not getting assignTo the controller

Tags: controller, picklist, apex-param

I have create a VF page from where i am trying to pass the value to controller. I have a picklist on which when i change the picklist value i need to send this value to controller.  But the changed value is not assigned to the controlled.
My code :

```
 <apex:column headerValue="Field">                           
                              <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!query.Field__c}" >  
                                        <apex:selectOption itemLabel="--None--" itemValue="--None--"></apex:selectOption>    
                                        <apex:selectoptions value="{!fieldlist}">  </apex:selectoptions>

                                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  action="{!updateOperatorList}">
                                            <apex:param name="selectedValll" assignTo="{!FieldValue}"  value="{!query.Field__c}"  />
                                        </apex:actionSupport>   
                              </apex:selectlist>                            
                        </apex:column>
```

please guide me where i am getting wrong.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, @Anu?